# Does ruby have the Java equivalent of synchronize keyword?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, synchronize

Does ruby have the Java equivalent of synchronize keyword? I am using 1.9.1 and I don't quite see an elegant way to do this.

Comment: You may want to try my Ruby gem [syncem](https://github.com/yegor256/syncem), which will make all methods in your object synchronized

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It doesn't have the `synchronize` keyword, but you can get something very similar via the `Monitor` class. Here's an example from the Programming Ruby 1.8 book:

```
require 'monitor'

class Counter < Monitor
  attr_reader :count
  def initialize
    @count = 0
    super
  end

  def tick
    synchronize do
      @count += 1
    end
  end
end

c = Counter.new
t1 = Thread.new { 100_000.times { c.tick } }
t2 = Thread.new { 100_000.times { c.tick } }
t1.join; t2.join
c.count → 200000
```

Comment: This is BTW a general programming language design principle: only crappy programming languages need keywords or new language features for everything. Well-designed languages can do it simply in a library.

Comment: You also don't have to inherit from Monitor if you don't want to. Just include the MonitorMixin module (which also gets brought in by `require 'monitor'`) in your class and you get the same behavior for free.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Looks like we found a LISP programmer ;)

Comment: I just comment out `synchronize do` and answer still the same: `200_000`. Where is the trick?

Comment: I add another answer with explanation how `synchronize` works. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30840316/1698467 Hope it helps to feel the difference.

Answer (score 14):

**The accepted answer doesn't represent how `synchronize` works!**

You can just comment out `synchronize do` and run accepted answer's script - output will be the same: `200_000`!

So, here is an example, to show the difference between running with/without `synchronize` block:

### Not thread safe example:

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby

require 'monitor'

class Counter < Monitor
  attr_reader :count
  def initialize
    @count = 0
    super
  end

  def tick i
    puts "before (#{ i }): #{ @count }"
    @count += 1
    puts "after (#{ i }): #{ @count }"
  end
end

c = Counter.new

3.times.map do |i|
  Thread.new do
       c.tick i
  end
end.each(&:join)
puts c.count
```

In the output you will get sometihing like that:

```
before (1): 0
after (1): 1
before (2): 0
before (0): 0 <- !!
after (2): 2
after (0): 3 <- !!
Total: 3
```

When the thread `(0)` started, `count` was equal to `0`, but after adding `+1` its value was `3`.

#### What happens here?

When the threads are starting they see the initial value of **`count`**. But when each of them, try to add `+1`, the value became different as result of the parallel computation. Without a proper synchronization, the partial state of **`count`** is unpredictable.

### Atomicity

Now we call these operations **atomic**:

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby

require 'monitor'

class Counter < Monitor
  attr_reader :count
  def initialize
    @count = 0
    super
  end

  def tick i
    synchronize do
      puts "before (#{ i }): #{ @count }"
      @count += 1
      puts "after (#{ i }): #{ @count }"
    end
  end
end

c = Counter.new

3.times.map do |i|
  Thread.new do
       c.tick i
  end
end.each(&:join)
puts c.count
```

Output:

```
before (1): 0
after (1): 1
before (0): 1
after (0): 2
before (2): 2
after (2): 3
Total: 3
```

Now, by using `synchronize` block, we ensure the **atomicity** of the add operation.

*but threads still running in random order (1->0->2)*

For detailed explanation, your can continue reading [this article](http://lucaguidi.com/2014/03/27/thread-safety-with-ruby.html).